# How to pass method dependencies in Dagger 2 at runtime

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I have a bit complex scenario. Let me first post the code then explain `FragmentModule`

```
 @Module
    public class FragmentModule
    {
        @Provides
        public static PickerDashboardFragment providesPickerDashboard()
        {
            PickerDashboardFragment fragment = new PickerDashboardFragment();
            return fragment;
        }

        @Provides
        public static PickingFragment providesPickingFragment()
        {
            PickingFragment fragment = new PickingFragment();
            return fragment;
        }

        @Provides
        public static PickingItemsFragment providesPickingItemsFragment()
        {
            PickingItemsFragment fragment = new PickingItemsFragment();
            return fragment;
        }

        **Note this**
        @Provides
        public static StagedItemsFragment providesStagedItemsFragment(ArrayList<PickJava> pickedList)
        {
            Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
            arguments.putParcelableArrayList("picked_list", pickedList);
            StagedItemsFragment fragment = new StagedItemsFragment();
            return fragment;
        }
    }
```

Here is `FragmentComponent`

```
@Component(modules = {FragmentModule.class, FragmentUtilsModule.class})
public interface FragmentComponent
{
    void inject(PickerDashboardActivity target);

    void inject(PickerDashboardFragment target);

    void inject(PickingFragment target);

   **Note this**
    StagedItemsFragment stagedItemsFragment();
}
```

Very important part. Requesting injection and this is how i'm building my component inside Fragment.

```
    public class PickingFragment extends Fragment{

    FragmentComponent component

    @Inject
        PickingItemsFragment pickingItemsFragment;

    @Override
        public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

      component = DaggerFragmentComponent
                    .builder()
                    .fragmentUtilsModule(new FragmentUtilsModule(this))
                    .build();
            component.inject(this);
    }

**Note this**
@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
    // Here i need StagedItemsFragment stagedItemsFragment(); from FragmentComponent
replaceNestedFragment(component.stagedItemsFragment());
}
```

But the problem is that the fragmentComponent is already built. Now as you can see in the `FragmentModule` `providesStagedItemsFragment` method requires `ArrayList<PickJava> pickedList` as a argument. How can i pass this. Please help or ask more details if required.

Comment: It was already explained to you in an answer to one of your previous similar questions that it is not a good idea to provide Fragments in modules. Is there any reason why you think that advice is invalid?

Comment: @DavidRawson sorry for late  replying to that one. Please check my comment over there.

Comment: But for now please tell me how to achieve above.

Comment: The first step is to stop providing Fragments in the modules and use static factories instead. Please study the sample project that is linked in the previous question.

Comment: I have a demo, I can change my implementation later but please tell me how to do above using Dagger

Comment: This is not a duplicate. It's a lot different scenario. Please stop marking everything duplicate without even reading the whole question.

Comment: @DavidRawson just suppose the above module is not a fragmentmodule and is different class then how to achieve above using dagger. Please try to understand i can't change the implementation right now.